# dropdown menus javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am completely new to javacsript/jquery and am working on a small app for browsers. I am trying to include dropdown menus like those on Facebook for notifications or new messages. Does anyone have any good starting advice or good references? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well basically it's just a divd that displays when you click. So if you're using jQuery you should be able to style the div and then `$("#div").show();` I'd say it's more like a submenu than a dropdown.

this should be something to go by
http://sammaye.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/facebook-style-css-jquery-drop-down-menus/

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery's LightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) is hugely popular for doing popout menus. I personally prefer to roll my own, but as far as plugins go, lightbox is the breadwinner.

Comment: OP wants a dropdown menu not lightbox!

Comment: @Raminson - popout is the new dropdown!